# Why Isn't My JQuery replaceWith() Working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to accomplish a seemingly simple task. I want to replace the displayed testimonial with a new random testimonial on button click. I'm using JQuery and PHP. Unfortunately, absolutely nothing happens when I click the button. Here is my code:

```
<div id="home-slogan">

<?php

    $filename = "testimonials/testimonial.txt"; #specify file
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");              #open file
    $numLines = count(file($filename));         #count number of lines
    $lines = file($filename);                   #read lines into array
    $randomTestimonial = rand(0,$numLines);     #generate random number
?>

<h1 id="heading" align="center">"<?php echo $lines[$randomTestimonial];?>"</h1>
<button type="button" id="next">Next Testimonial</button>

<script>

    var randomTestimonial = <?php echo $lines[$randomTestimonial];?>;

    $("#next").click(function(){
    $("#heading").replaceWith(randomTestimonial);
    });

</script>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: For one thing you will probably need quotes around the javascript part: `var randomTestimonial = '<?php echo $lines[$randomTestimonial];?>';`

Comment: Secondly, `$randomTestimonial` is not regenerated, so it will probably be the same as the string between the `<h1>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I've fixed it, but the button still isn't working. In fact, I've tried replacing the randomTestimonial variable with a string (in quotations, lol) with no results.

Comment: Lastly, the scope of this code allows for only 2 messages to be created, one in the `<h1>` tag and the other assigned to the `var`. For more than just one, you would need Ajax or an array of values.

Comment: Try using `$("#heading").html(randomTestimonial);`

Comment: You're right, it's not regenerated. I'll look at fixing that. However, I'm still just trying to get the button to do something (anything, lol). If I can make the button work, I'll see about regenerating the variable.

Comment: I have tried $("#heading").html(randomTestimonial); with no success...

Answer (score 1):

You're probably generating a syntax error (opening your console with <kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows) because your string isn't quoted.

```
var randomTestimonial = '<?php echo addslashes($lines[$randomTestimonial]); ?>';
```

As for changing the text in the header, you probably want to do something more like this.

```
$('#next').click(function() {
  // Since right now randomTestimonial isn't regenerating
  $('#heading').text('Random text'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I've fixed it, but the button still isn't working. In fact, I've tried replacing the randomTestimonial variable with a string (in quotations, lol) with no results.

Comment: @user1100793 See my edit about how to get the button to work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried your code and the button still does nothing. I'm beginning to think there is a more fundamental error somewhere... maybe a script type conflict or something?

Comment: @user1100793 Very unlikely. Try adding `alert('Hey!')` to your click handler and see if you get the alert. If not, the script is not being loaded or there is still a syntax error. Make sure to check your console for errors.

Comment: I tried adding the alert with no success. The error I'm getting from the console is: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: That's because you aren't including jQuery. Before your script, add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `html` or `text`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8cvtxjt6/

```
<h1 id="heading" align="center">"test is best"</h1>
<button type="button" id="next">Next Testimonial</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    var randomTestimonial = "glue";
    $("#next").click(function(){
        $("#heading").html('"'+randomTestimonial+'"');
    });
</script>
```

Also, check your console for errors. It may tell you something more than what you have shown.

Comment: Your suggestion works for me on jsfiddle. However, it does not work on my site. Also, I've check my console, and I'm getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Can you paste your final output (browser source)?

Comment: <div id="home-slogan">
                                            
        
    <h1 id="heading" align="center">"Will definitely recommend.
"</h1>
    <button type="button" id="next">Next Testimonial</button>
    
    <script>
     
  var randomTestimonial = "Hello";
  
  $('#next').click(function(){
   $('#heading').html('"'+randomTestimonial+'"');
  });
            
    </script>       
        
</div>

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery libraries included?

Comment: Yes, using Google's. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: That link is funky. If that's identical to what's in your page, that that might be your problem.